# How to attach data to view methods with django class based views and decorators?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have the following decorator:

```
def my_decorator(setting_value):

    def actual_decorator(func):
        func.my_setting = setting_value
        return func

    return actual_decorator
```

I'm trying to read `my_setting` in a context processor like so:

```
# Resolve the url
try:
    page_resolve = resolve(request.path_info)
except Resolver404:
    return {}

# Get the page view function
page_view = page_resolve.func

if (page_view.my_setting):
    return extra_context_data
else
    return {}
```

This whole scheme falls apart when using CBVs. How do I make the decorator compatible with both FBV and CBV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the decorator to `dispatch` function:

```
class MyView(View):
    @my_decorator
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```